# Can't find the error QT

Tags: c++, qt

I get this error for all set functions
error: expected primary-expression before '.' token:
             All.push_back(Country.setName(country[0]));
                                  ^

this is repository.cpp

```
#include "repository.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>


void Repository::PopulateList()
{
    QFile file(":/countries.txt");
    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QTextStream str(&file);
        while (!str.atEnd())
        {
            QString line = str.readLine();
            QStringList country = line.split(" ");
            All.push_back(Country.setName(country[0]));
            All.push_back(Country.setArtist(country[1]));
            All.push_back(Country.setSong(country[2]));
            All.push_back(Country.setScore(0));
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

this is repository.h

```
#ifndef REPOSITORY_H
#define REPOSITORY_H
#include <country.h>
#include <QString>
#include <vector>

class Repository
{
    private:
        std::vector<Country> All;
        void PopulateList();
    public:
        Repository();
        std::vector<Country> getAll(){return this->All;}
};

#endif // REPOSITORY_H
```

What am i doing worng?

Comment: you have to instantiate `Country` in order to use the instance methods on it... If this is not clear to you, I seriously recommend reading a good book about C++ first

Comment: @IceFire has the answer.

Comment: @IceFire Country is instantiated

Comment: It doesn't look like that.

Comment: `Country` is the class, an instance would have to have a different name. Please learn what "instantiate" means before claiming that you do instantiate

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add "Country" objects to your list you need to declare one, set it your values and then add it to your list :

```
QString line = str.readLine();
QStringList country = line.split(" ");
Country myCountry;
myCountry.setName(country[0]);
myCountry.setArtist(country[1]);
myCountry.setSong(country[2]);
myCountry.setScore(0);
All.push_back(myCountry);
```